# How to run kexec with currently running kernel and initrd

Tags: grub2, kernel, dbus

I'm currently login as "`root`",

I want to use `kexec` to load a new kernel from the currently running kernel and then login as "`normal_user`" when booting the kexec kernel.

**Here is an example usage of kexec:**

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/kexec-command-examples-in-linux/

```
kexec -l path/to/kernel --initrd=path/to/initrd --reuse-cmdline
```

I want to use `kexec` to login as "`normal_user`" when booting from that "`path/to/kernel`":

**Here is the expected usage:**

```
# echo "now the user is root"
# kexec -l path/to/kernel --initrd=path/to/initrd --reuse-cmdline --login-as-user "normal_user"
# echo "now the user is normal_user, run d-bus command for the normal_user"
```

How to find the real "`path/to/kernel`" and "`path/to/initrd`" from the currently running ubuntu 22.04?

And how to `login-as-user` in the kexec commmand line?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Man page for `kexec`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/kexec.8.html), and look inside your `/boot` folder.

As stated on the Man page:

> ```
> For example, if the kernel image you want to reboot to is /boot/vmlinux, the  contents  of
> /proc/cmdline  is  root=/dev/hda1,  and  the  path to the initrd is /boot/initrd, then you
> would use the following command to load the kernel:
>
>       kexec -l /boot/vmlinux --append=root=/dev/hda1 --initrd=/boot/initrd
>
> After this kernel is loaded, it can be booted to at any time using the command:
>
>       kexec -e
> ```

For modern Ubuntu systems, the current kernel is `/boot/vmlinuz` and the current kernel ramdisk is `/boot/initrd.img` (as evident by looking in `/boot`).

So in this case, your command would be:

```
kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz --initrd=/boot/initrd.img --reuse-cmdline
```

And after it's loaded, execute with:

```
kexec -e
```

For Ubuntu, I don't see the `--login-as-user` option documented anywhere.