# Is it possible to reload kernel with new settings (currently configured in grub) without a full reboot?

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kernel, kvm-virtualization

I setup Ubuntu 20.04 awhile back with two main use cases:

1. Run calculations on eGPU using cuda on the host. This is configured in `/etc/default/grub` with the default line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
2. Use VFIO to enable GPU passthrough to a KVM guest. This is done by telling the linux kernel to ignore the eGPU and set the appropriate ID to be reserved for the virtual machine. This is also configured in `/etc/default/grub` with the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash module_blacklist=nvidia,nvidia_drm,nvidia_uvm,nvidia-peermem,nvidia_modeset intel_iommu=on iommu=pt kvm.ignore_msrs=1 vfio-pci.ids=10de:1b06,10de:10ef"`

Each of these use cases work great independently, but when I want to swap the eGPU from one to the other, I need to edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, run `sudo update-grub`, and reboot.

Is it possible to reload the kernel with different settings, equivalent to those configured by `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` at runtime? Or generally, achieve the same result as above without using grub and pass these settings somewhere else? Being able to keep other unrelated, CPU-bound processes running when needing to swap between use cases 1 and 2 would be really useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run kexec with currently running kernel and initrd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484959/how-to-run-kexec-with-currently-running-kernel-and-initrd)

Comment: To "keep other unrelated, CPU-bound processes running", you might want to investigate whether you can just move the GPU to and from the VM: https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/fbk04s/linux_gpu_passthrough_and_dynamic_attachdetach/

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks, kexec is good to know about. I just tried it out and it can reload kernel options without a full reboot (skip hardware checks). But I guess I'm looking for something even "softer", so I can keep other VMs/processes running.

Comment: @DanielT This might be exactly what I'm looking for! If only fully detailed guides like this existed back when I first did the setup! Thanks!